# This page isn’t working right now localhost can't currently handle this request. HTTP ERROR 500

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

I am trying to access a function in CodeIgniter some pages(function) are working but some are showing error like that

## controller

i am also trying to redirect function in dummy view page but still it shows this page......

```
 public function search() {
  $this->load->view('dummy');
    }
```

## view

```
<?php
            if ($this->module_lib->hasActive('OPD')) {
                if ($this->rbac->hasPrivilege('opd_income_widget', 'can_view')) {
                    ?>

                    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col20
                         ">
                        <div class="info-box">
                            <a href="<?php echo site_url('admin/patient/search') ?>">
                                <span class="info-box-icon bg-green"></span>
                                <div class="info-box-content">
                                    <span class="info-box-text"><?php echo $this->lang->line('opd') . " " . $this->lang->line('income'); ?></span>
                                    <span class="info-box-number"><?php
                                        if (!empty($opd_income)) {
                                            echo $currency_symbol . $opd_income;
                                        } else {
                                            echo "0";
                                        }
                                        ?></span>
                                </div>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div><!--./col-lg-2-->
                    <?php
                }
```

```
# .htaccess
```

````
                     <ifModule mode_env.c>
                      SetEnv CI_ENV development
                     </IfModule>

                       RewriteEngine On
                       RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
                       RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
                       RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]

                     ```
````

look at code above and and Thankyou in Advance for your valuable time                     ```

Comment: Take a look into your http server's error log file. That is where you can simply read what the cause of the issue is.

Comment: You _need_ to check your server's error log. This looks like a PHP error, not `.htaccess`/mod_rewrite. This is impossible to answer without more information. You will get an HTTP 500 response if there is any kind of fatal error in your PHP code and display_errors is Off.